# How to create xml file with multiple element in python

Tags: python, xml

I want to create an XML file using python
like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <vehicle id="m0">
     <timestep  pos="2.3000" angle="11.1766" lane="-250709918#7_0" speed="0.0000" time="8.0" 
  </vehicle>

  <vehicle id="m1">
     <timestep  pos="2.3000" angle="11.1766" lane="-250709918#7_0" speed="0.0000" time="8.0" 
  </vehicle>
  ........
```

my code:

```
doc = xml.dom.minidom.Document()
root = doc.createElement('vehicle')
for veh in veh_dict:
   root.setAttribute('id', veh)
   doc.appendChild(root)
   for index, value in enumerate(veh_dict[veh]):
       nodeManager = doc.createElement('timestep')
       nodeManager.setAttribute('time', str(veh_dict[veh][index]['time']))
       nodeManager.setAttribute('angle', str(veh_dict[veh][index]['angle']))
       nodeManager.setAttribute('lane', str(veh_dict[veh][index]['lane']))
       nodeManager.setAttribute(' pos', str(veh_dict[veh][index]['pos']))
       nodeManager.setAttribute('speed', str(veh_dict[veh][index]['speed']))
       nodeManager.setAttribute('type', str(veh_dict[veh][index]['type']))
       nodeManager.setAttribute('x', str(veh_dict[veh][index]['x']))
       nodeManager.setAttribute('y', str(veh_dict[veh][index]['y']))
       root.appendChild(nodeManager)
fp = open('Manager.xml', 'w')
doc.writexml(fp, indent='\t', addindent='\t', newl='\n', encoding="utf-8")
```

My output has all datas, but they are all written in one of the 'vehicle'
like this:

```
<vehicle id="m2.9">
    <timestep  pos="2.3000" angle="11.1766" lane="-250709918#7_0" speed="0.0000" time="8.0" type="custom_moto" x="469.2605" y="5896.8761"/>
    <timestep  pos="3.3001" angle="12.9664" lane="-250709918#7_0" speed="1.0001" time="9.0" type="custom_moto" x="470.1134" y="5907.0132"/>
    <timestep  pos="6.4467" angle="12.2144" lane="-250709918#7_0" speed="3.1466" time="10.0" type="custom_moto" x="470.849" y="5900.3489"/>
    <timestep  pos="12.7147" angle="11.8696" lane="-250709918#7_0" speed="6.2681" time="11.0" 
    .......
```

Is the root always being overwritten?
How can solve it?

Comment: can you provide a sample of your veh_dict

Comment: @lrh09  veh_dict is a dictionary .The example inside is: `[{'x': '469.2605', 'y': '5896.8761', 'time': 8.0, 'lane': '-250709918#7_0', 'angle': '11.1766', 'pos': '2.3000', 'speed': '0.0000', 'type': 'custom_moto'}, {'x': '470.1134', 'y': '5907.0132', 'time': 9.0, 'lane': '-250709918#7_0', 'angle': '12.9664', 'pos': '3.3001', 'speed': '1.0001', 'type': 'custom_moto'}]`

Comment: Where do you get the vehicle `id` from? It's not in `veh_dict`.

Comment: Your desired XML is not well-formed. To be rules compliant, you need a root tag above `vehicle` elements.

Answer (score 2):

Add the root element inside the loop:

```
import xml.dom.minidom

doc = xml.dom.minidom.Document()
topElem = doc.createElement('vehicles')

for veh in veh_dict:
   for index, value in enumerate(veh_dict[veh]):
       root = doc.createElement('vehicle')
       root.setAttribute('id', veh)
       doc.appendChild(root)
       nodeManager = doc.createElement('timestep')
       nodeManager.setAttribute('time', str(veh_dict[veh][index]['time']))
       nodeManager.setAttribute('angle', str(veh_dict[veh][index]['angle']))
       nodeManager.setAttribute('lane', str(veh_dict[veh][index]['lane']))
       nodeManager.setAttribute(' pos', str(veh_dict[veh][index]['pos']))
       nodeManager.setAttribute('speed', str(veh_dict[veh][index]['speed']))
       nodeManager.setAttribute('type', str(veh_dict[veh][index]['type']))
       nodeManager.setAttribute('x', str(veh_dict[veh][index]['x']))
       nodeManager.setAttribute('y', str(veh_dict[veh][index]['y']))
       root.appendChild(nodeManager)
       topElem.appendChild(root)
fp = open('Manager.xml', 'w')
doc.writexml(fp, indent='\t', addindent='\t', newl='\n', encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.If executed in this way, `xml.dom.HierarchyRequestErr: two document elements disallowed` will appear

Comment: I almost forgot. In XML, you need to nest all the elements inside one root element. So you have to create an element at the top like `vehicles` and then add all the nested `vehicle` elements inside it. Please check the updated code

Comment: Please consider approving the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a top-level root above `<vehicle>` elements as required for [well-formed XML documents](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-well-formed). Also, avoid the repetitious lines and use the inner dictionary keys as the iterator variable. Finally, use context manager, [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/compound_stmts.html#with), to write built XML to file.

```py
import xml.dom.minidom

# LIST OF DICTS
veh_dicts = [{'x': '469.2605', 'y': '5896.8761', 'time': 8.0, 'lane': '-250709918#7_0', 
              'angle': '11.1766', 'pos': '2.3000', 'speed': '0.0000', 'type': 'custom_moto'}, 
             {'x': '470.1134', 'y': '5907.0132', 'time': 9.0, 'lane': '-250709918#7_0', 
              'angle': '12.9664', 'pos': '3.3001', 'speed': '1.0001', 'type': 'custom_moto'}]

doc = xml.dom.minidom.Document()
root = doc.createElement('vehicles')             # TOP-LEVEL ROOT
doc.appendChild(root)

# ITERATE THROUGH EACH DICT
for i, veh in enumerate(veh_dicts, start=1):
   vehichleElem = doc.createElement('vehicle')
   vehichleElem.setAttribute('id', f'm{i}')      # USES F-STRING (Python 3.6+)
   root.appendChild(vehichleElem)
   
   nodeManager = doc.createElement('timestep')   
   for k in veh.keys():
      nodeManager.setAttribute(k, str(veh[k]))      
   vehichleElem.appendChild(nodeManager)
   
with open('MiniDomXMLBuild.xml', 'w') as fp:     # CONTEXT MANAGER (NO close() NEEDED)
    doc.writexml(fp, addindent='\t', newl='\n', encoding="utf-8")
```

Output

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vehicles>
    <vehicle id="m1">
        <timestep angle="11.1766" lane="-250709918#7_0" pos="2.3000" speed="0.0000" time="8.0" type="custom_moto" x="469.2605" y="5896.8761"/>
    </vehicle>
    <vehicle id="m2">
        <timestep angle="12.9664" lane="-250709918#7_0" pos="3.3001" speed="1.0001" time="9.0" type="custom_moto" x="470.1134" y="5907.0132"/>
    </vehicle>
</vehicles>
```